# Allow math problems in string input (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, math, input, eval

Is there a way to parse math equations as input using JavaScript?

for example, when a user enters "10-25" as input, it is parsed to -15

I tried using `eval`, which works, but it allows users to run all JavaScript code, not just math equations.

If it's possible, I'd like to also allow some functions, like `sin()`, `cos()`, and `degreesToRadians()`, but not all functions.

examples

```
"5" //returns 5
"12-20" //returns -8
"3/2" //returns 1.5
"sin(3.14)" //returns 0.00159265292
"sin(degreesToRadians(180/2)) * 10" //returns 10

"alert('hi')" //doesn't work
```

Comment: Are you asking to turn the math equation string into what it evaluates to?

Comment: There's nothing built into javascript for this, but various libraries are available. Or you can implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split expression by math operations and check them.

Next code does it for: ( ) / *

```
mathExpression.replace(/([()/*])/g, " $1 ").split(" ").filter(v => v);
```

```js
var allowedCommands = ["(", ")", /^\d*\.?\d*e?$/, "*", "/", "+", "-", "sin", "cos", "degreesToRadians"];

function checkCommand(arg) {
  return allowedCommands.some(v => {
    if (v instanceof RegExp) {
      return v.test(arg)
    } else {
      return v == arg;
    }
  });
}

function checkAllowedCommands(mathExpression) {
  var commands = mathExpression.replace(/([()/*+-])/g, " $1 ").split(" ").filter(v => v);
  var filterNotAllowedCommands = commands.filter(v => !checkCommand(v));
  return filterNotAllowedCommands.length == 0;
}


console.log(checkCommand("degreesToRadians"));
console.log(checkCommand("234"));

console.info("right expression");
console.info(checkAllowedCommands("sin(degreesToRadians(180/2)) * 10"));
console.info(checkAllowedCommands("(1.2e-6)"))
console.info(checkAllowedCommands("sin(1+2)"));

console.warn("wong expression");
console.info(checkAllowedCommands("alert('hi')"));
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to be working completely. when i do checkAllowedCommands("(12)") or checkAllowedCommands("sin(10)"), it returns false. it seems like it doesn't work if the input starts or ends with ( or ).

Comment: You were right. Splitting with the above RegEx added an empty string to the array and the empty string doesn't exist in the list of allowed commands. I added a filter after the split for non empty commands.

Comment: it still doesn't seem to work completely. addition and subtraction still doesn't work

Comment: I thought you'd figure it out. You just need to add math operators to the following code:

    var commands = mathExpression.replace(/([()/*+-])/g, " $1 ").split(" ").filter(v => v);

Comment: one last thing- is there a way to make it work with scientific notation? something like 1e5 or 1e+5

Comment: RegEx inside allowedCommands variables checks number format. I updated it:

 /^\d*\.?\d*e?$/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nerdamer

I've used Nerdamer in a few projects in the past, and it's pretty solid. Short of that, there's no "simple" way to do it short of implementing your own mini-parser that I know of.